# Should I decline variable names in a documentation

Tags: variables, documentation

I'm currently writing a codumentation where I refer to my variables with their names, for example "value", and I also highlight them with a different font. When i want to refer to multiple same fields of different objects, should I then refer to it as "values"?

This case may not be that big of a deal, but I write the documentation in german (the example is only for you to grasp my problem), and here we decline every noun in every case. So when I need a genitive, should I just use the nominative form?

German example: Das ist der `wert`. So und so funktioniert die Berechnung des `wertes`/`wert`es/`wert`

Answers from german speaking people would be preferred, but I dig any help.

Comment: If that was in English, I will be confused as hell.

Comment: Probably off-topic here, but include a sample or two (in German). I would not change the name of symbols to fit grammar. Try to work work around it ("the `value`-fields" instead of "the `value`s"). And definitely don't let it leak into the monospace font ("the `value`s" if you must, but never "the `values`").

Comment: yep, added examples. thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bend grammar a little if necessary, don't change tense or case or pluralization or capitalization of variable names.

- So und so funktioniert die Berechnung von `wert`.
- So und so wird `wert` berechnet.
- Der Wert (grr...) für `wert` ergibt sich so und so.
- Nach Anpassung dieser Variablen (`wert`)